# Yii register CSS file, to be the last one (after assets)

Tags: php, css, yii, registration

Is there a way in Yii to register js or css files to load them after those loaded by the assets manager.

I use a css file to override styles from some Yii extensions, but Yii includes my file before the assets generated by the extension.

I know I can change the extension to remove the css files from the assets manager and add them manually with `registerCssFile` but that's not the way I want to do this.

Here's what I have :

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/MY_CSS.css" />
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e838803/css/EXTENSION_CSS.css" />
...
</head>
```

Here's what I want:

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8e838803/css/EXTENSION_CSS.css" />
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/MY_CSS.css" /> <!-- the last one -->
</head>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Registered assets by CClientScript are always added **before** the title

In your case you should add your CSS **after** the title, to guarantee the order you want

Comment: How to register my css files after title, in a static page like About which load by site.com/index.php/site/page?view=About  ??

Comment: @shgnInc the same rules apply as other pages, you cannot register css files after title using CClientScript, you need to do it manually.

Comment: @Asgaroth, Thank you, How to do it manually? You mean, i do that in view/layout/main.php file or any thing else?

Comment: Yes in view/layout/main.php if thats the one your view is using, manually I mean <link rel="stylesheet...

Comment: @Asgaroth, I need some css file just for a static view file. How to set the orders in this case, for once?

Answer (score 3):

In Yii2, a good way to accomplish this is by using the 'depends' option on registerCssFile as shown in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)

```
$this->registerCssFile("http://example.com/css/themes/black-and-white.css", [
    'depends' => [BootstrapAsset::className()],
    'media' => 'print',
], 'css-print-theme');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//example 1
class someWidget extends YourExtendsionClassName
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile('/path/to/your/css/file.css');
    }

    // or

    public function run()
    {
        Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile('/path/to/your/css/file.css');
            parent::run();
    }
}

//example 2

//Layouts file main.php

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<title>Title</title>
<?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile('/path/to/your/css/file.css'); ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.php layouts, find  tag, put this line code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/path/to/css/file');
```

http://www.codexamples.com/98/how-to-include-javascript-css-in-yii/